# Exchange 2016 email from internal application server to exchange

Tags: exchange

My exchange server 2016 (192.90.X.X) can't receive email that are triggered from my internal server 192.168.X.X, however this is working in previous email system. the system email and internal mailbox are all at the same domain name company.com

The email is triggered from my internal server scheduler to send email to exchange server internal user mailbox.

This scenario works in my previous Mdaemon email system, in the internal server/application they modified below setting to have the email triggered to internal users mailbox. i changed the application setting to point toward exchange server. but there's no email received for system@company.com or support@company.com.

Tested telnet exchange01 port 25 and the telnet was successful.

I created a custom connector and added the application server internal IP into the custom connector, still couldnt retrieve the email..

Configuration file in application:-

```
<!-- Email Setting -->
<add key="ServerName" value="exchg01.company.com" />
<add key="Username" value="system@company.com" />
<add key="Password" value="XXXX" />
<add key="Port" value="25" />
<add key="EnableSsl" value="false" />
<add key="SupportEmail" value="support@company.com" />
```

How can i make this work in exchange 2016?

Comment: Are you sure that the server name is spelled correctly? Have you tried having the application use the ip address of the server instead of the name?

Comment: Read Exchange SMTP log.

Comment: Is "support@company.com" a valid email address in your environment?  If so, you would have to delegate the appropriate permission to allow the system@company.com user to send as support@company.com.

Comment: As mentioned in the above reply, you need to check it out. In addition, have NDRs return to senders? What errors show in NDR?

Comment: Hi joy, no there's no ndr return to the sender..

Comment: Hi, the support@company.com is a valid mailbox, did you mean that i would need to add support@company.com as the send as permission?

Comment: Minami - Just because you can connect to the SMTP server from [`192.168.X.X`] the IP of the same machine which the email is triggered is not enough to troubleshoot I don't think. You also need to move forward with the other commands via telnet to send an email to the address which the trigger does and post those results with an [edit]. When you connect to the Exchange server via telnet, do it using the same URL as your triggered process will use or the IP address if that's what it is using. If it's using a URL and you are using an IP in your telnet testing, that may not emulate accurately

Comment: (cont...) When going from the client to the same URL from the same machine the triggered email launches "the email that never delivers nor sends an NDR", be sure any MX appliances or router hops along the way allow the needed traffic thru with applicable rules, ACLs, etc. There may also be other logs to look over as well but confirm with an Exchange Server log somewhere that you see the message hitting the Exchange services on this server if you feel it is with other testing and see what it indicates may be the problem.